# real time audio stream using jack on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, clojure, jack, noir

What would be the best way to live stream audio from an application running through jack on an ubuntu server?

My site is built with noir and clojure, but I am generally trying find where to start with achieving this. The audio is generated using Overtone running through jack and I am hoping to capture the audio and stream it live. Is this even possible or will I have to render to a .wav of .mp3 and then only have playback? thanks for any info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#jack) (along with [ffserver](http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html)) would be the first choice to do something like this.